# First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I'm recently practicing React Native and developing a signup form attached to Firebase.

But whenever I tried to click the button, it gives an error:

> createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed first argument email must be a valid string.

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {Button,Input} from 'react-native-elements';
import firebase from './screens/firebase';

console.log(firebase.name);
console.log(firebase.database());

class App extends React.Component
{

constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name:'',
    email : '',
    Password : '',
    tc:'',
    phone:'',
    };
}

handleRegisterUser = () => {
    const {name,email,Password,tc,phone} =this.setState;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,Password)
    .then((user) => {
        const fbRootRefFS = firebase.firestore();
        const userID = user.uid;
        const userRef = fbRootRefFS.collection('users')
        .doc(userID);
        userRef.set({
            name,
            email,
            Password,
            tc,
            phone,
        });
    })
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>

      <Input
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}/>

      <Input
        placeholder='Enter Email'
        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>

      <Input
        placeholder='Enter Password'
        onChangeText={(Password) => this.setState({Password})}/>

       <Input
        placeholder='Enter TC'
        onChangeText={(tc) => this.setState({tc})}/>

        <Input
         placeholder='Enter Phone'
         onChangeText={(phone) => this.setState({phone})}/>

    <View style={{marginTop : 40,flexDirection : 'row'}}>

     <Button
       title="Sign UP"
       onPress = {() => this.handleRegisterUser(this.state.name,this.state.email,this.state.Password,this.state.tc,this.state.phone)}/>
      </View>
     </View>
      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container :
  {
    flex : 1,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems : 'center',
  }
});

export default App;
```

Where am I making a mistake? I have been dealing with this problem for a long time, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `handleRegisterUser()` you need to retrieve the value from the state this way:

```
const {name,email,Password,tc,phone} = this.state;
```

`this.setState` is a function used to update the state of the component. You can access the state using `this.state`.

See the [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state) for reference.

Comment: Now new error occur : Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was : undefined

Comment: @chc probably because your `userID` is undefined. Try to catch any error from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function.